# Embedded Video Player Hiding Website Menu

Tags: html, css

I am using an embedded video player. The player controls are hiding my website menu when paused. How do I put the website menu above the player completely?

Site Link:
https://academy.easyenglish.pk/lesson/details/easy-tenses/subject-

[screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIGTQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add:

```
.left-side-lesson-list {
    z-index: 100;
}
```

It already has `position: fixed;`, [read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).